# SQLで特定の番号以下の人たちだけを、月別で集計したい

Tags: sql

SQL初心者です。
初歩的な質問となり恐縮ですが、ご教示頂けると幸いです。

number90以下の人たちだけを、月別で集計したいのですが、
その構文をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の例ですと、20180823は3、20180930は2、とゆうような情報が欲しいです。]

Answer (score 2):

```
create table mytable (
    datetimesend date,
    id char(1),
    number integer
);

insert into mytable (datetimesend ,id, number ) values 
    ('2018-08-23','a',34),
    ('2018-08-23','b',23),
    ('2018-08-23','c',95),
    ('2018-08-23','d',78),
    ('2018-09-30','e',50),
    ('2018-09-30','f',6),
    ('2018-09-30','g',99)
;
```

単純に、`where`句で指定すれば良いと思いますが、どうでしょうか。

```
select sum(number) as sum, year(datetimesend) as year, month(datetimesend) as month
from mytable where number <= 90 group by year,month;
```